# on click of button,window is reloading and getting multiple errors using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> On click of complete button I am getting multiple errors such as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

> My complete button is defined as:
>
> > angularjs .js is defined in common xhtml

```
 <html lang="en" ng-app="onboardApp">
     <head>
      <meta content="" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../mobile/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../mobile/resources/bootstrap/css/theam.css"/><!-- 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../mobile/resources/js/formService.js"></script> -->
     </head>
     <style>
     .text{
        resize:none;
     }
     </style>
     <body style="overflow-y:auto;">
        <div class="container-fluid onboardFormCntrlElement" style="padding-right:10px;         background-color:rgb(239,239,239)!important; width:71%; margin-left:14%; height:326px" ng-controller="onboardFormCntrl">
            <h3 style="color: #2196F3; margin-left: 35%; margin-top: 16px;">Invite Colleagues</h3>
            <form name="invitecolleaguesForm" class="invitecolleaguesForm" style="margin-top:2px;overflow-y:auto;max-height:710px;max-width:600px;overflow-x:hidden;" action="">
                <div class="row">
                <!-- <div class="emailError"></div> -->
                <label><h6 style="margin-left:117px! important; padding:0px;"><b>Your Domain is:</b></h6></label>
                <span style="font-weight:bold">
                {{domain}}
                </span>
                </div>
                    <label><h6 style="margin-left:103px! important;"><b>Enter email addresses of your colleagues to invite  them to use Sigmify.</b></h6></label>
                <div class="row">
                    <textarea class="text" ng-model="foo" style="margin-left:17%; height:34%; width:69%;"></textarea>
                    <!-- <input required="true" ng-readonly="readOnly=='true'" type="email" ng-model="email_id" name="email_id" ng-maxlength="100" style="margin-left:17%; height:34%; width:69%;" ng-pattern="/^[\W]*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}[\W]*,{1}[\W]*)*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})[\W]*$/"></input> -->
                </div>
                <div style="width:77%; margin-left:78px">
                    <label><h6 style="margin-left:26px! important; font-style: italic;">You can use comma or semi-colon to separate the email addresses. And you can invite people from your domain only.</h6></label>
                </div>
                <div class="complete" ng-click="complete(); return false;" style="display: flex;align-items:            center;justify-content: center;">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-4">
                    <button class="btn pull-right" ng-click="complete(foo);" style="margin-top: -16px; margin-right:11px; line-height:11px;height:25px;width: 100px !important;font-size: 11px !important;font-weight:bold !important;font-family:Arial !important;background: rgb(136,185,93) !important;color: rgb(255,255,255) !important;"
                    tabindex="3"> Complete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

> Not able to understand what are these errors actually?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with the error, at first glance it seems like angular widget issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are facing version compatibility issue with your jquery. For example using older version of jquery for eg. jquery 1.9 or something similar.

Try adding **jquery migrate plugin** using the below line :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

You can also follow this [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) to read full documentation for the above plugin.

Hope it helps !

Comment: It was  null check error in my js file,I forgot to check and add e.preventDefault(); in else part.